# wget, curl or whatever: get filename only in case of 302 redirect

Tags: redirect, wget

I want to download some files but first check if I got them already.
Problem is, I don't have their real URLs but they are behind 
a 302 redirection. See the wget output:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: ./epub/balzac_37_un_grand_homme_de_province_a_paris.plain.epub [following]
--2016-02-26 19:38:29--  http://www.ebooksgratuits.com/epub/balzac_37_un_grand_homme_de_province_a_paris.plain.epub
```

Now this "./epub/balzac_37_un_grand_homme_de_province_a_paris.plain.epub"
string is exactly what I would like to have, but WITHOUT downloading,
because I want to check if I have the file already and can avoid downloading.

Is it possible to tell wget, curl or whatever tool
to give me that local path without downloading?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this does the job:

```
curl -w "%{redirect_url}" URL
```

Without the -L option, it doesn't download from the new place,
and with -w "%{redirect_url}" it prints the desired redirect URL.

Still have to investigate in order to be sure...